# Using multiple joins (e.g left join)

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know what's the logic for multiple joins (for example below)

`SELECT * FROM B` returns 100 rows

`SELECT B.* FROM B LEFT JOIN C ON B.ID = C.ID` returns 120 rows

As I know using left join will returns any matching data from the left table which is B if data are found for both table. But how come when using `left join`, it returns more data than table B itself?

What am I do wrong or misunderstood here? Any guidance are very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be table B:

```
id
----
1
2
3
```

Let be table C

```
id     name
------------
1      John
2      Mary
2      Anne
3      Stef
```

Any id from b is matched with ids from c, then id=2 will be matched twice. So a left join on id will return 4 rows even if base table B has 3 rows.

Now look at a more evil example:

Table B

```
id
----
1
2
2
3
4
```

table C

```
id     name
------------
1      John
2      Mary
2      Anne
3      Stef
```

Every id from b is matched with ids from c, then first id=2 will be matched twice and second id=2 will be matched twice so the result of

```
select b.id, c.name
from b left join c on (b.id = c.id)
```

will be

```
id     name
------------
1      John
2      Mary
2      Mary
2      Anne
2      Anne
3      Stef
4      (null)
```

The id=4 is not matched but appears in the result because is a left join.

Comment: You are talking about formatting text on Stack Overflow? You have a button when you are in Edit mode. Its effect is to indent the lines with 4 or 5 spaces and the result is _code style_ formatting.

Comment: Hi again, so I use DISTINCT to eliminate the duplicate data retrieved from C then my query output will be data only from B right?

Comment: Hmm, not really. This depends on what columns you select.

Comment: No. Test it with fewer data. if table C has different values on other column on the same id, then Distinct will not produce unique data from B. Set a good test case and post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following example :

```
B = {1,2}
C = {(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(1,d),(1,e)}
```

The result of `B left join C` will be :

```
1 | a
1 | b
1 | c
1 | d
1 | e
2 | null
```

The number of rows in the result is definitely larger than rows in B (2).

In general the number of rows in result of `B left join C` is bounded by `B.size + C.size` and not only by `B.size` as you think...

Answer (score 0):

As per your query it do the join to B Table with C and B table is Left Table so it will display all the records of Left table in our case it is B and related from other Table in our Case it is C.